# Display an interactive image with pins on top

Tags: flutter, pinchzoom

I need to build a widget which loads an image (floor plan) with pins on it, with set coordinates, but at the sametime the image needs to be zoomable and can be moved, while the pins keep their size and correct location.

You can see bellow an image about what I mean by image with pins.
[image: Floor map]

I have looked into some packages which load images, but they don't seem to have to a builder where I can add a stack and the pins.

I am trying to work with [InteractiveViewer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html), but so far I encountered the following issues:

- cannot manage to keep the size of the pins, constant (to not change size while zooming);

Anyone has any suggestions or recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InteractiveViewer` takes in different callback functions that allow you to keep track of the current scale ([`onInteractionUpdate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer/onInteractionUpdate.html) being the main one you'll use here).

Use this to keep track of the current scale of the interactive viewer in the state of your widget (using the [`scale`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/ScaleUpdateDetails/scale.html) property on `ScaleUpdateDetails`).

Then, wrap each marker in a [`Transform.scale`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.scale.html) (with the origin set to the bottom of the pin) and do some calculation (e.g `1 / currentScale`) to determine which scale would directly counteract that of the interactive viewer.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the assist, while I couldn't find a proper solution using InteractiveViewer, I managed to do it using https://pub.dev/packages/zoom_widget package and it's zoom property. 
My issue was finding out how I can calculate the current scale, based on what scale from ScaleUpdateDetails.

Still, it was due to your answer that it stirred me in the right way.